# Python function to find a point of an equilateral triangle

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am trying to write a function `equilateral(x, y):` that takes two `np.ndarrays of shape (N,)`   , where x and y are natural numbers and returns a point z `an np.ndarray of shape (N,)` such that (**x**, **y**, **z**) are are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Any one please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You said x and y are natural numbers, and you said x and y are one dimensional arrays of shape N.  Which is it?  One number, or many numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following program.
You may also expand the code to **test** if the distance between the points is equal.

```
    import numpy as np
    def equilateral(x, y):
                    
        v_x = (x[0]+y[0]+np.sqrt(3)*(x[1]-y[1]))/2 # This computes the `x coordinate` of the third vertex.
        v_y = (x[1]+y[1]+np.sqrt(3)*(x[0]-y[0]))/2 #This computes the 'y coordinate' of the third vertex. 
        z = np.array([v_x, v_y]) #This is point z, the third vertex. 
        return z
```

Comment: What if we have x, y as n dimensional? e.g. `x = np.array([2,0,3,4]) y = np.array([5,0,0,8])`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the third vertex, you could just rotate the point (x2, y2,...) by 60 degrees around point (x1, y1,...). The other admissible solution would be obtained with a rotation by -60 degrees, i.e., in the opposite direction.

So just rotate y around x by 60/-60 degrees and you have your 3rd co-ordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there will be **two** points that can make an equilateral triangle with the given two points

```
import math

# define the coordinates of the first two points
x1, y1 = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 3, 4

# calculate the distance between the two points
distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

# calculate the angle between the two points
angle = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)

# calculate the coordinates of the third point (the first one)
x3_1 = x1 + distance * math.cos(angle - (1 * math.pi / 3))
y3_1 = y1 + distance * math.sin(angle - (1 * math.pi / 3))

# calculate the coordinates of the third point (the second one)
x3_2 = x1 + distance * math.cos(angle + (1 * math.pi / 3))
y3_2 = y1 + distance * math.sin(angle + (1 * math.pi / 3))
```